# Get active listings (by eBay location / country)

Tags: python, ebay-api, trading

We list products on eBay internationally (same product, multiple eBay locations)

I'm trying to get a list of `ActiveListings` so we can compare eBay against our local store (we can make sure if we run out of inventory that we have killed the listing promptly as we sell on multiple channels.)

Using the `GetMyeBaySelling` call as follows returns me ALL listings, but with no way of knowing which eBay location they are listed on/from.

This results in the same product, returned multiple times. I wish to know / check by eBay location.

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetMyeBaySelling.html#GetMyeBaySelling

I'm using the eBay Python SDK.

```
def get_active_listings(page):
    acitvelist = api.execute('GetMyeBaySelling', {'ActiveList': True,
                                                  'DetailLevel': 'ReturnAll',
                                                  'PageNumber': page})
    return acitvelist.dict()
```

Once I've used the .dict() method to turn it into a Python dictionary (returning all possible details) gives me this as an example product:

```js
{
  'QuantityAvailable': '2',
  'ItemID': 'xxxx',
  'PictureDetails': {
    'GalleryURL': 'xxxxx'
  },
  'ListingDetails': {
    'ConvertedBuyItNowPrice': {
      'value': '47.41',
      '_currencyID': 'USD'
    },
    'ViewItemURLForNaturalSearch': 'xxxxxx',
    'ViewItemURL': 'xxxxxx',
    'StartTime': '2016-10-04T12:27:56.000Z'
  },
  'ClassifiedAdPayPerLeadFee': {
    'value': '0.0',
    '_currencyID': 'USD'
  },
  'Quantity': '2',
  'WatchCount': '1',
  'TimeLeft': 'PT33S',
  'SellerProfiles': {
    'SellerShippingProfile': {
      'ShippingProfileName': 'Flat:DPD Two Day(Free),DPD Next Day/Flat:Stan#2',
      'ShippingProfileID': '64944860016'
    },
    'SellerReturnProfile': {
      'ReturnProfileID': '67182036016',
      'ReturnProfileName': 'Returns Accepted,Buyer,14 days#13'
    },
    'SellerPaymentProfile': {
      'PaymentProfileID': 'xxxxx',
      'PaymentProfileName': 'PayPal'
    }
  },
  'BuyItNowPrice': {
    'value': '38.5',
    '_currencyID': 'GBP'
  },
  'ListingType': 'FixedPriceItem',
  'SellingStatus': {
    'CurrentPrice': {
      'value': '38.5',
      '_currencyID': 'GBP'
    },
    'ConvertedCurrentPrice': {
      'value': '47.41',
      '_currencyID': 'USD'
    }
  },
  'SKU': 'brubu1sp',
  'ListingDuration': 'GTC',
  'Title': 'Brunswick Soprano Ukulele, Purple (NEW)',
  'ShippingDetails': {
    'ShippingServiceOptions': {
      'ShippingServiceCost': {
        'value': '0.0',
        '_currencyID': 'GBP'
      }
    },
    'ShippingType': 'Flat'
  }
}
```

I'm unable to find a satisfactory answer to this.

Comment: Meant to add - the returned data has no information regarding eBay store location etc

Comment: May I suggest: 1. Reread your question's text, and add the few missing words. That way it'd stop being incomprehensible. 2. If you need to change the OP, do it there (maybe note that it's an edit) and not in a comment.